# Python taking input as list of integers

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take input as list of integers. Here is my attempted code

```
input_binary = int(list(input("enter a binary number: "))) # taking a user input as integers
```

Here is the error it is throwing

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Have any idea?

Comment: What's your example input ?

Comment: int() only takes string , for example int("3") -> 3

Comment: My example input is 11

Comment: so you want to convert 11 to [1,1] right ?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve here. Correct me if I am wrong, are you trying to convert a list of strings to a list of integers? For example, are you trying to convert this list ["1", "2", "3"] to [1,2,3] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a list into an integer (at least, not with `int()`), which is what you're trying to do. Instead, try doing things in the other order.

Say you want a list of 5 integers:

```
binary = []
for _ in range(5):  # do the following 5 times
    inp = int(input("enter a binary number: "))  # take user input as string, convert to int
    binary.append(inp)  # put that int into our list
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have input "123456" and output [1,2,3,4,5,6]

```
input_string = [int(num) for num in input("enter a binary number: ")]
print(input_string)
```

Result:

```
enter a binary number: 123456
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```